# How to apply a dictionary across a row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary that the key of year, and the corresponding value of a list of values. Is there a way to apply that value across the row of a dataframe. For instance if my key is "1995" how do I apply element 1 of the dictionary to column 1, element 2 to column 2 and etc for the whole entire dictionary?

my dictionary is as follows:

```
my_dict = {'1995' : [.99,.98,.96],'1994' : [.9995,.986,.97]}
```

now I have a dataframe
organized as such

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'issue year' : {1995,1994}
'legal entitiy':  {'a',"a"}
'x': {100,98}, 
'y': {98,97},
'z':{95,80})
```

I wish to apply across each row such that for 1995 we hit 100 with .99,98 with .98 anda 95 with .96

1994 would get 98 with .995, 97 with .986  and so on. If there was a 3rd year column x y and z would have one more entry and each would get hit with a factor for that year.

```
 pd.DataFrame({'issue year' : {1995,1994}
    'legal entitiy':  {'a',"a"}
    'x': {100*.99, 98 * .9995}, 
    'y': {98*.98, 97*.986},
    'z':{95*.96, 80 * .97})
```

Comment: Like this? `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'1995': [1, 2, 3]}, orient='index')`

Comment: so I created the dictionary that has those values, but now I have another dataframe and I want to multiply 
column 1 by 1 , column 2 by 2 and column 3 by 3, given that the value in column 0 is 1995

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I'm not really sure what you want.  I threw something up in the comment that might help you.  But if you really need more help, then you're going to need to provide more information.  Please click and read this -> [mcve].  Once we have that going, it makes it a ton easier to answer your question.

Comment: ok thank you. I am going to post my code. I am not sure how to post a dataframe snippet. but I will try.

Comment: @piRSquared I updated my question to have more info.

Comment: @N27 what would really help here is if you also typed out what your expected result is (as a dataframe like you did with the input)

Answer (score 0):

First you transform your dictionary into a Dataframe with the names of the columns you want to apply your operation on e.g.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index',columns=['x','y','z'])
df_1.index = df_1.index.astype(int)
```

Then you can use slices to select the part of dataframe you want to perform the operation on and the use a standard arithmetic operator.

```
df = df.set_index('issue year')
df.loc[df_1.index,df_1.columns] = df.loc[df_1.index,df_1.columns]*df_1
df = df.reset_index()
```

Which will result in the desired dataframe

Comment: so I think I asked my question a bit poorly. I reworded it better. Do you think this solution applies still?

Comment: Yes, it does still apply

Comment: So I was able to get something going like this but there are two issues I am having
1) some of the items in df_1 are not in df (the dictionary has more values than the data). For instance in my dictionary we have data for 2001 but the data has only year 1994 and 1995 and 1996, how do I handle this key error? Secondly, does this work if there are multiple entries for a given index in the data (df).

Thanks! @Arnau